# Minimum number of iterations

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

We are given an array with numbers from ranging from 1 to n (no duplicates) where n = size of the array.
We are allowed to do the following operation :
arr[i] = arr[arr[i]-1] , 0 <= i < n

Now, one iteration is considered when we perform above operation on the entire array.
Our task is to find the number of iterations after we encounter a previously encountered sequence.

```
Constraints :  
a) Array has no duplicates
b) 1 <= arr[i] <= n , 0 <= i < n  
c) 1 <= n <= 10^6
```

Ex 1:

```
n = 5  
arr[] = {5, 4, 2, 1, 3}  

  
After 1st iteration array becomes : {3, 1, 4, 5, 2}  
After 2nd iteration array becomes : {4, 3, 5, 2, 1}  
After 3rd iteration array becomes : {2, 5, 1, 3, 4}  
After 4th iteration array becomes : {5, 4, 2, 1, 3}    
In the 4th iteration, the sequence obtained is already seen before  
So the expected output is 4.
```

This question was asked in one of job hiring tests, so I dont have any link to the question.
There were 2 sample test cases given out of which I remember one which is given above. I would really appreciate any help on this question

P.S.
I was able to code the brute force solution, where in I stored all the results in a Set and then kept advancing to the next permutation. But it gave TLE

Comment: what is *your* question? What help do you need?

Comment: Yes,  as @StPiere said I need a hint or an algorithm. I was not able to think any optimal solution. I was only able to code the brute force, but it gave TLE

Comment: @crazyCoder How did you store the results in a set ? as strings ? Maybe a Trie data structure is more suitable for storing already  encountred permutations

Answer (score 0):

First, note that an array of length n containing 1, 2, ..., n with no duplicates is a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation).

Next, observe that `arr[i] := arr[arr[i] - 1]` is *squaring* the permutation.
That is, consider permutations as elements of the [symmetric group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) S_n, where multiplication is composition of permutations.
Then the above operation is `arr := arr * arr`.

So, in terms of permutations and their composition, the question is as follows:

> You are given a permutation p (= arr).
> Consider permutations p, p^2, p^4, p^8, p^16, ...
> What is the number of distinct elements among them?

---

Now, to solve it, consider the [cycle notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation) of the permutation.
Every permutation is a product of disjoint cycles.
For example, `6 1 4 3 5 2` is the product of the following cycles: `(1 6 2) (3 4) (5)`.
In other words, every application of this permutation:

- moves elements at positions 1, 6, 2 along the cycle;
- moves elements at positions 4, 3 along the cycle;
- leaves element at position 5 in place.

So, when we consider p^k (take an identity permutation and apply the permutation p to it k times), we actually process three independent actions:

- move elements at positions 1, 6, 2 along the cycle, k times;
- move elements at positions 4, 3 along the cycle, k times;
- leave element at position 5 in place, k times.

Now, take into account that, after d applications of a cycle of length d, it just returns all the respective elements to their initial places.
So, we can actually formulate p^k as:

- move elements at positions 1, 6, 2 along the cycle, (k mod 3) times;
- move elements at positions 4, 3 along the cycle, (k mod 2) times;
- leave element at position 5 in place.

---

We can now prove (using [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), or just using general knowledge of group theory) that the permutations p, p^2, p^3, p^4, p^5, ... are all distinct up to p^m, where m is the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of all cycle lengths.
In our example with p = `6 1 4 3 5 2`, we have p, p^2, p^3, p^4, p^5, and p^6 all distinct.
But p^6 is the identity permutation: moving six times along a cycle of length 2 or 3 results in the items at their initial places.
So p^7 is the same as p^1, p^8 is the same as p^2, and so on.

---

Our question however is harder: we want to know the number of distinct permutations not among p, p^2, p^3, p^4, p^5, ..., but among p, p^2, p^4, p^8, p^16, ...: p to the power of a power of two.
To do that, consider all cycle lengths c_1, c_2, ..., c_r in our permutation.
For each c_i, find the pre-period and period of 2^k mod c_i:

- For example, c_1 = 3, and 2^k mod 3 look as `1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, ...`, which is `(1, 2)` with pre-period 0 and period 2.
- As another example, c_2 = 2, and 2^k mod 2 look as `1, 0, 0, 0, ...`, which is `1, (0)` with pre-period 1 and period 1.

In this problem, this part can be done naively, by just marking visited numbers mod c_i in some array.

By Chinese Remainder Theorem again, after all pre-periods are considered, the period of the whole system of cycles will be the least common multiple of all individual periods.

What remains is to consider pre-periods.
These can be processed with your naive solution anyway, as the lengths of pre-periods here is at most log_2 n.
**The answer** is the least common multiple of all individual periods, calculated as above, plus the length of the longest pre-period.